# Convert string in dictionary format to dictionary using python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a string in dictionary format like:

```
{'fossils': [{Synset('dodo.n.01'): {'of', 'is', 'out', 'someone', 'fashion', 
'whose', 'style'},Synset('fossil.n.02'): {'age', 'that', 'an', 'has', 'past', 
'from', 'excavated', 'plant', '(',')', 'and', 'animal', 'in', 'remains', 
'geological', 'soil', 'existed', 'impression', 'of', 'or', 'been', 'the', 'a'},
 Synset('fossil.a.01'): {'of', 'a', 'fossil', 'characteristic'}}], 
'disturbing': [{Synset('disturb.v.01'): {'me', 'This', 'upset', 'thought','book', 
'deeply','move', 'troubling', 'A'}, Synset('agitate.v.06'): {'of', 'or', 
'arrangement', 'the', 'position', 'change'}, Synset('touch.v.11'): {'my', '!', 
'touch', 'Do', 'tamper', 'with', 'CDs', "n't"}, Synset('interrupt.v.02'): {'of', 
'or', 'peace', 'tranquility', 'destroy', 'the', 'I', 'me', 'interrupt', 'Do', 
'reading', 'when', "'m", "n't"}}]}
```

I want to convert this into a dictionary. The format of the dictionary is

```
{key: list of dictionaries as value}
```

Please help me to sort this out

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have "Objects" (called Synset). usually, you can do this sort of convert with json.loads(str) to get the value of the dictionary.
because you have the objects, you need to fix this manually (pre-process the string prior to the json.loads) and later post-process to have the objects back.

edit: moreover, you have multiple types of parantheses which might humper things when loading the string.

edit2: There is of course another option (if your Synset class is known and you trust it's source):

`import Synset # for swift conversion
dict_val = eval(dict_like_str)`

I'll also add these lines in my original

Comment: @student of course, as I noted earlier: "moreover, you have multiple types of parentheses which might hamper things when loading the string".

There is of course another option (if your Synset class is known and you trust it's source):
`
import Synset # for swift conversion
dict_val = eval(dict_like_str)
`
I'll also add these lines in my original